# How to concat one to many attributes with foreign key link

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the schema below. I am trying to join the `genre`s and `genre_of_movie` together to have a commar delimiter list of the movie's genre. Now very sure how to do it.

```
CREATE TABLE movies (
  id integer AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
  name varchar(100)
);

CREATE TABLE genres (
  id integer AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
  name varchar(100)
);

CREATE TABLE genre_of_movie (
  id integer AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
  movie_id integer,
  genre_id integer,
  FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (genre_id) REFERENCES genres(id)
);

INSERT INTO movies (name) VALUES ('Joker');
INSERT INTO genres (name) VALUES ('actions'), ('romance'), ('drama');
INSERT INTO genre_of_movie (movie_id, genre_id) VALUES (1, 1), (1, 3);
```

What I want:

```
+-------+---------------+
| movie |  genre_list   |
+-------+---------------+
| Joker | action, drama |
+-------+---------------+
```

My attempt

```
SELECT m.name, g.name
FROM movies m
JOIN genre_of_movie gom ON m.id =  gom.movie_id
JOIN genres g ON gom.genre_id = g.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```sql
SELECT m.name, GROUP_CONCAT(g.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS genre_list
FROM movies m
INNER JOIN genre_of_movie gom ON m.id =  gom.movie_id
INNER JOIN genres g ON gom.genre_id = g.id
GROUP BY m.name;
```

### Demo

Note that technically two different movies could happen to have the same name.  In this case, we could aggregate by movie `id` and `name`, to display different movie `id` values in this case:

```sql
SELECT m.id, m.name, GROUP_CONCAT(g.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS genre_list
FROM movies m
INNER JOIN genre_of_movie gom ON m.id =  gom.movie_id
INNER JOIN genres g ON gom.genre_id = g.id
GROUP BY m.id, m.name;
```

Comment: That gives me `actions,,drama,` as the result: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c0a8b/8 There are 2 commas?

Comment: How do I make it so it gives `actions, drama`

Comment: But now there is no space after the commar like `, ` Its just `,`

Comment: Thanks. I will mark this as the answer when it lets me